# MySQL - Right join OR Right join

Tags: mysql

I'm building a social application.

I'd like to select all the posts, that the user has interacted with in some way (liked, commented, or liked a comment)

How could I achieve that? I'm imagining something like this:

```
SELECT p.* FROM posts p
    RIGHT JOIN postLikes pl ON pl.postId = p.id AND pl.userId = :userId
    OR
    RIGHT JOIN postComments pc ON pc.postId = p.id AND pc.userId = :userId
    OR
    RIGHT JOIN postCommentLikes pcl ON pcl.postId = p.id AND pcl.userId = :userId
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT :startIndex, 20
```

I'd like to achieve this in one query, because I have a paging system (20 posts / page)

Using `UNION ALL` would mess up this system.

See:

```
SELECT res.* FROM ((SELECT p.*, p.id AS postId FROM posts p
    RIGHT JOIN postLikes pl ON pl.postId = p.id AND pl.userId = :userId)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT * FROM posts p.*, p.id AS postId
    RIGHT JOIN postComments pc ON pc.postId = p.id AND pc.userId = :userId)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT * FROM posts p.*, p.id AS postId
    RIGHT JOIN postCommentLikes pcl ON pcl.postId = p.id AND pcl.userId = :userId)) AS res
GROUP BY postId
ORDER BY postId DESC LIMIT :startIndex, 20
```

This way **the order would be messed up**, and therefore I wouldn't know what's the right `startIndex`

Comment: @forpas Left join would select all the posts, even though the user hasn't interacted with it.

Comment: I misread the question.... Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` like this:

```
SELECT p.* FROM posts p
WHERE 
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM postLikes pl WHERE pl.postId = p.id AND pl.userId = :userId)
  OR
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM postComments pc WHERE pc.postId = p.id AND pc.userId = :userId)
  OR
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM postCommentLikes pcl WHERE pcl.postId = p.id AND pcl.userId = :userId)
ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT :startIndex, 20
```

or with `UNION` and the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT postId FROM postLikes WHERE userId = :userId
  UNION 
  SELECT postId FROM postComments WHERE userId = :userId
  UNION 
  SELECT postId FROM postCommentLikes WHERE userId = :userId
) 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :startIndex, 20
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was looking for!